# How to hide horizontal overflow absolute element

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I'm using tailwind. I want to create a layout with a fixed-size image. My container is 1200px and centering viewport.

The image will be overflow when the viewport is smaller, but I want to hide the overflow part of the image. That means the user can't scroll to view it. Thanks

Here is my code: https://play.tailwindcss.com/YVOEhykx1E

Answer (score 1):

Here, Is the little update! I think you can do more better by exploring documentation

```
<div class="h-screen mx-auto bg-red-500 grid grid-cols-12 gap-8 overflow-hidden">
  <div class="col-span-12 col-start-8">
    <img class="object-cover h-full w-full" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1640686708297-e6dc01470fb8?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1740&q=80" alt="" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you misunderstand my purpose. I need to disable horizontal scroll made by the image, not fit the image to the container :(

Comment: Could you check now?

Comment: You missed important information like the image is fixed size. it must have width 1044px and height is 380px, the container is 1200px and mx-auto